# cowplot plot_grid function to plot table as image and dendrogram

Tags: r, cowplot

I am trying to use the plot_grid function from cowplot to make a customized plot with a dendrogram on the top row and two tables(next to each other)on the second row. Now what ends up happening is my dendrogram and tables get plotted, but on two separate PDF's. Is there a way to have them all plot on the same page? Below is my code snippet:

```
 pdf("test.pdf", width = 12, height = 10)
 x <-tableGrob(frames[[1]])
 y <-tableGrob(frames[[2]])
 plot.clus <-plot(test1,label=diseaseDuration,main=label)
 tables<-grid.arrange(x,y,nrow=1)
 plot_grid(bottom_row,tables)
```

snippet of the dput output for clustering(hclust):

```
 structure(list(merge = structure(c(-61L, -41L, -49L, 1L, -16L...), 
 height = c(4.23833720098634e-13, 6.36507320251999e-13.......),
 order = c(5L, 57L, 12L, 7L, 66L, 31L, 55L, 6L, 10L, 37L,..),
 labels = c("ABC00001", "ABC00002", "ABC00003",......),
 method = "ward.D", 
 call = hclust(d = data, method = "ward.D"), dist.method = 
 "euclidean"), .Names = c("merge", "height", "order", "labels", "method", "call", "dist.method"), class = "hclust")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `plot.clus` in place of `z` plot

```
library( 'ggplot2' )
library( 'cowplot' )
library( 'gridExtra' )

x <- tableGrob( d = data.frame( x = 1:5, y = 1:5 ) )
y <- tableGrob( d = data.frame( x = 1:5, y = 1:5 ) )
z <- ggplot( data = data.frame( x = 1:5, y = 1:5 ), 
             mapping = aes( x = x, y = y ) ) + 
  geom_line( color = 'red' )

p <- ggdraw() +
  draw_plot( plot = z, x = 0, y = .5, width = 1, height = .5 ) +  # z
  draw_plot( plot = x, x = 0, y = 0, width = .5, height = .5 ) +  # x
  draw_plot( plot = y, x = .5, y = 0, width = .5, height = .5 ) + # y 
  draw_plot_label( label = c( "A", "B", "C" ),                    # labels
                   x = c( 0, 0, 0.5 ),
                   y = c( 1, 0.5, 0.5 ), 
                   size = 16 )
# save plot as pdf
save_plot( filename = "test.pdf", plot = p, base_height = 4, base_width = 4 )
```

Comment: Sathish, thanks for your response. The above didn't really work as my plot.clus is not a ggplot or gtable class object. I get the following error:    
      Error in ggplot_to_gtable(plot) : 
  Argument needs to be of class "ggplot" or "gtable"

Comment: post your data used for cluster diagram by doing `dput(data)`. did you use hierarchical cluster algorithm?

Comment: please add the output of `dput` command in your question, not in the comment section

Comment: Sathish: Yes, I used hierarchal clustering. I have added sample of my dput output.

Comment: the data you provided there will not  help. You would better try `ggdendro` package yourself to create ggplot compatible dendrogram.

Comment: Thanks Satish, that helped. I have one question though, how to decrease the height of the tables obtained from tableGrob?

Comment: Tablegrob has a theme argument which can be used to adjust various parameter. Google fo tablegrob and theme